# What is the meaning of Conjugate radius and Injectivity radius?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry

I review the text book of  differential geometry and I find that the conjugate radius and injectivity radius are still enigmatic for me. Here is a quetion which I confuse it. I don't think it is true, but I don't know how to disprove it. Can one give a counter-example or some literatures?

A smooth Riemannian metric bigger than the stand metric on sphere (ie, g > g_st) , if the conjugate/injectivity radius will bigger than  π？

More generally: if we see the conjugate/ injectivity radius on a smooth closed manifold as a function on the space of Riemannian metric with smooth topology (or other topology), can it be continuous?  Even more, can it  increase when the metric increase?

Comment: I don't know about the condition you give, but I think if $\operatorname{Ric} \geq \operatorname{Ric}_{st}$, then $\operatorname{inj} \leq \operatorname{inj}_{st}$ by standard Jacobi field comparisons. See various comparison geometry notes by Eschenberg, Wei, Li and Schoen as well as the classic text by Cheeger and Ebin.

Comment: @Paul, thanks for your information. On the sphere, g ≥ g_st  means the inner product of g bounded below by the stand one in every point for every two tanget vectors. It looks like need the curvature condition to give the lower bound π of the conjugate raduis.